# jQuery Check if multiple elements have a class

Tags: html, jquery

I need to run a function inside a conditional statement based on whether or not 3 elements have a class.

In short, if (elm1, elm2, elm3) have the class "include" then ring true. But all 3 elements must have the class, it can not ring true if only 2 or 1 has the class.

```
<div class="elm1" class="include"></div>
<div class="elm2" class="include"></div>
<div class="elm3" class="include"></div>

jQuery('#search-submit').click(function() { 
    if (#elm1, #elm2, #elm3).hasClass('include'){
        /* return true */
    } else {
        /* return false */
    }
}
```

Needless to say this doesn't work.

Comment: Are you interested in executing the "true section" only if all 3 `<div>` elements have the "include" class? Or do you only need at least 1? (If you need 3, I'm quite certain the answer you accepted is wrong, but by all means - validate this)

Comment: @Amit : Yes your right I did select the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to correct your markup, since you can't have multiple identical attributes in a single element (As Jai noticed...):

```
<div class="elm1 include"></div>
<div class="elm2 include"></div>
<div class="elm3 include"></div>
```

Once you do, you can use a combined selector, and check your length:

```
jQuery('#search-submit').click(function() { 
    if (jQuery('.elm1.include, .elm2.include, .elm3.include').length == 3){
        /* return true */
    } else {
        /* return false */
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no id attributes.

Comment: @AlexKnopp - if this answer helped you, I'd appreciate an upvote (so that at least it offsets the pointless downvote)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
<div class="elm1 include"></div>
<div class="elm2 include"></div>
<div class="elm3 include"></div>

 var classNotFound = false;
 $('.elm1, .elm2, .elm3').each(function() {
     if (!$(this).hasClass('include')){
        classNotFound = true;
     }
 });
 return classNotFound;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is not correct, put `id="elm1"` and not `class="elm1"` (for all three elements). Also there are some syntax error like 
1. `jQuery('#search-submit')` - this block must ends with `});`
2. put your selector inside quotes , in your case `if (#elm1, #elm2, #elm3)`
3. if condition must be inside `()`

You can have array of id of all elements and iterate it to know if element has class or not and set flag accordingly.

```js
var elements = ['#elm1', '#elm2', '#elm3'];
jQuery('#search-submit').click(function() { 
    var result = true;
    //iterate all elements ids
    jQuery.each(elements, function(i, v){
       //set result false if element don't have class
       if(!jQuery(v).hasClass('include'))
          result = false;
    });
    //show final result
    alert(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elm1" class="include"></div>
<div id="elm2" class="include"></div>
<div id="elm3" class="include"></div>

<input id="search-submit" type="button" value="Click me">
```

Answer (score 0):

*Needless to say this doesnt work.*

Surely!

Why:

Because of the multiple `class` attributes. If this happens then one is ignored, instead you can do this:

```
<div class="elm1 include"></div>
<div class="elm2 include"></div>
<div class="elm3 include"></div>
```

and in the js you have a selector with `id` which is not as per markup. My suggestion is to use `.filter()` method to filter out divs as per class you want to check and you can return it from `.filter()` then you can do your work as per your need.

So this can be done:

```js
jQuery('#search-submit').click(function() {
  jQuery('div').filter(function(e, elem) {
    return !jQuery(this).hasClass('include');
  }).addClass('exclude');

  // just a demo:

  $('div').html(function(){
      this.innerHTML = '<pre>'+ this.classList +'</pre>'
  });
 
});
```

```css
.include {
  color: green;
}
.exclude {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elm1 include">inclue</div>
<div class="elm2">!include</div>
<div class="elm3 include">include</div>
<br>
<button id="search-submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: And you must pay attention to requirements: *But all 3 elements must have the class*. :-)

Comment: That's ok, we're at a tie :-)

Comment: That's still wrong, although almost like my answer, and yet you got the upvote... How is that? (You forgot to compare the length to 3)

Comment: @Amit do you know what is `0` in js and what is other numbers other than negative numbers.

Comment: @Amit 0 in js is interpreted as `false` and other positive values are `true`, so this is why there is no need to check for length to 3.

Comment: No, that's not true. the requirement is (again) "*all 3 elements must have the class*". While 0 is false, 2 is true, but it's not 3. But appareantly, OP doesn't really care :-)

Comment: I don't get into fights and downvote wars, but as I already noted twice, this answer is wrong, and it's a shame OP doesn't even notice that.

Comment: @Amit how do you know this answer is wrong? The way you are behaving seems that you are here to get points that is all. Right it doesn't matter what have you learned so far in js still i would recommend to go to MDN to read js.

Comment: It took a little while to get OP's reaction, but now you also know your answer is wrong. You should know better than disrespecting with snark comments - you *know* my JS knoweldge isn't lacking. It's all about whether or not the answer is correct - that's it. It's a shame you decided to revenge with a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Note you have used `class` attribute instead of `id` and so on for the rest:

```
<div class="elm1" class="include"></div>
```

Your JS code where I assume you tend to use id instead of class

```
if (#elm1, #elm2, #elm3)
```

Sample working code with ids:

```js
$(function() {
  var inc = $('div.include[id^=elm]').length;
  var all = $('div[id^=elm]').length;
  alert(all === inc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elm1" class="include"></div>
<div id="elm2" class="include"></div>
<div id="elm3" class="include"></div>
```

Sample working code with class:

```js
$(function() {
  var inc = $('div.include[class^=elm]').length;
  var all = $('div[class^=elm]').length;
  alert(all === inc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="include elm1"></div>
<div class="include elm2"></div>
<div class="include elm3"></div>
```

Comment: That works until the OP has an element like `<div class="elmtree"></div>` anywhere in their document.